# Meaning of 僕も兎だった

Tags: meaning

僕も兎だったけど、よくお裾分けで渡してたんだ。
The only thing I understand from the first part is I was also a rabbit.
This doesn't fit with the context since the person saying this is without a doubt a human.
Any other meaning for this phrase? Or is this a typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 僕も兎だったけど、よくお裾分けで渡してたんだ。

I think 僕も modifies 渡してたんだ, but not 兎だった.

From the source that l'électeurさん provided, we can't find other people who hunt rabbits, so も doesn't make sense if 僕も modifies 兎だった.

Now a rough translation would be:

> Though it was (no more than) rabbit meat, I was also providing some meat to the shop.

Comment: So the も here is because his father provided the meat, and he himself also provides it?

Comment: I think so. In this sentence the position of 読点 ("、") is so bad that it makes us feel that 僕も and 兎だったけど are connected.

Answer (score 9):

If that sentence is taken from here:

http://cache.yahoofs.jp/search/cache?c=-cLtO13x8wQJ&p=%E2%80%9D%E5%83%95%E3%82%82%E5%85%8E%E3%81%A0%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%E2%80%9D&u=ncode.syosetu.com%2Fn8366dn%2F14%2F

it makes perfect sense.  「僕{ぼく}も兎{うさぎ}だった」 means:

> "what I had (from my hunting) was rabbit meat"

Japanese is an incredibly contextual language.  Not much of what we say informally would make any sense if you translated it into English or any other languages.

For instance, I always say 「ボクは犬{いぬ}です。」 to mean "***I was born in the year of the dog***." in a situation where someone asks me what animal zodiac year I was born in.  No one will think that I said "I'm a dog (, not a human)."

In an eatery, we say things like 「アタシはコーヒー。」、「僕はアイスティー」, etc. to tell the clerk what we want to order.  This is my favorite subject, but I will stop here.  Once again, direct translation will not work.

Comment: So も is basically a 'also' version of は?

Comment: No, not in this context.  The reason I gave that TL was mostly because I never thought this was a question about も to begin wth.  As you could tell from the other examples I gave, I was only concerned about explaining how we say "I am coffee, dog, etc." the way English speakers do not.  も is a complex word and it would be better if it were treated as a separate question.  From the way you asked your question, I never was able to tell you were concerned about that も at all.

Comment: I wasn't really concerned about that も, but that particular phrase. But I thought your explanation on the context usage relates to it.